# displaying vertical scrollbar in my code

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am going through a code in my HTML document and came across the following code where code samples are getting inserted. Here is the code I am referring to.

```
 <div class="api-content-item" data-ng-show="verb.code != undefined">
    <h5>Code Samples:</h5>
    <ul class="example-lang">
      <li data-ng-repeat="ex in verb.code">
        <a data-ng-click="exampleCode(ex.uri, $parent.$index)">
          {{ex.lang}}
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="document-clear"></div>
    <div hljs 
       data-line source="verb.examplecodedata" 
       class="doc-code-example" 
       data-ng-init="exampleCode(verb.code[0].uri, $index)"></div>
 </div>
```

The problem is that, the code doesn't have vertical scrollbar but horizontal scrollbar. So for instance, if I have 400 lines of code to display on my HTML document, its consuming lot of space and showing all the code which I don't want.

Is there any thing in Angular JS with which I can include vertical scrollbar in my above code? Please advise. Thanks

When I use the following CSS:

```
.doc-code-example {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    /*max-height:60%;
    overflow-y:scroll;*/
    background: #fff;
    /*overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;*/ 

}
```

The scrollbars scenario look like following: [image: following]:

However, when I use the following CSS,

```
.doc-code-example {
    /*overflow-x: scroll;*/
    max-height:60%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 

}
```

the scroll bar looks like following [image]: A vertical impression gets created and horizontal scroll bar changes it's color but still exists. I am wondering what's going wrong?

Comment: isn't that more of a css thing?

Comment: what rachel said, overflow-y if you will :P

Comment: edit this fiddle with your code http://jsfiddle.net/L8FpM/

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple css issue.

in your class  .api-content item, set a max-height e.g.

```
 max-height:60%;
```

and set your overflow-y to scroll

```
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x:hidden;
```

That should do it. If you add these lines in the html rather than the div, a vertical scroll will apply everywhere and not just for that particular div.

add

```
 overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
```

for FF support

Comment: you can use percent or pixels for the max height. percent is generally better practice

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did try including `overflow-y:scroll;` in the class `doc-code-example` where I have `overflow-x: scroll;` already defined but for some reason, I am seeing an impression of vertical scrollbar getting created but there doesn't appear to be any scroll bar present which is weird.

Comment: get rid of the overflow-x if you don't want horixontal scrollbars. can you post your css? max-height is the key here though.

Comment: Sure, please find my updated code and css in my question. Thanks

Comment: The horizontal scrollbar disappears in this case but vertical remains the same, I mean its impression is there and not the actual scrollbar.

Comment: either reduce the max height for the arrows to appear or else there isn't enough data to fill it yet. Failing that switch to overflow-y:auto; with the max height reduced